Java class cannot be cast to itself. java.lang.ClassCastException: class models.User cannot be cast to class models.User
I'm learning Spring and Hibernate and trying to make a CRUD API.
I've written a method to get a user from the database.
public User read(int id) {
        Transaction transaction = null;
        User user = null;
        try (Session session = HibernateSessionFactoryUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession()) {
            transaction = session.beginTransaction();
            user = session.get(User.class, id);
            transaction.commit();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            handleException(e);
        }
        return user;
    }

If I call this method directly, it works:
UserDAO userDAO = new UserDAO();
System.out.println(userDAO.read(1));

Output: User{id=1, email='email', password='password', person=null}

But when I try to use this method through the controller:
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/users")
public class UserController {
    private final UserDAO userDAO = new UserDAO();

    @GetMapping("/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<User> findUser(@PathVariable(value = "id") int id) {
        return ResponseEntity.ok(userDAO.read(id));
    }
}


... it doesn't work and throws an exception on the line user = session.get(User.class, id):

java.lang.ClassCastException: class models.User cannot be cast to class models.User (models.User is in unnamed module of loader 'app'; models.User is in unnamed module of loader org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.classloader.RestartClassLoader @b688ea4)
    at dao.UserDAO.read(UserDAO.java:31)
    at controllers.UserController.findUser(UserController.java:22)
        at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:564)

I've tried to remove devtools, to exclude User class from reloading, to disable dev tools classes reload (that's what an AI told me to try), but none of that works.
I don't have a single idea on how to fix it...
Help me, please.

If you are using Hibernate like this in a Spring application you are doing it wrong. You are using Spring Boot which is making it even worse. Ditch the HibernateSessionFactoryUtil instead use the Spring Boot configured EntityManager and let Spring Boot autowire the things for you.Work with the framework not around it (like youare doing it now). When you have done that rerun your application.

The issue is most likely connected to class loading within module context.

@M.Deinum I am totally agree with you, but I was tasked to use Hibernate and thought that I have to do all this work by "my hands". I'll ask my mentor to let me use EntityManager, but I still want to understand the cause of the problem and get a solution.
Anyway, thanks for your answer!

Hibernate is a JPA implementation so technically you are still using Hibernate and even with plain hibernate (you could still inject the SessionFactory and still use the JPA configuration) and Spring this would be wrong.
